# Calculating probability of mutually exclusive outcomes

Tags: probability

This seems so likely easy and very likely contained in all of the other mutual exclusion questions, but I am brain frozen on how they get to the answer choices.

An experiment has 3 mutually exclusive outcomes with the probabilities of $p,p/2,p/4$. What is $p$?

Answer choices are $1/7,2/7,3/7,4/7,5/7$.

I think I understand that $P(A\cup B)=0$, even if there are multiple $P$.

But I'm confusing $P$ as probability and the events $p, p/2$ and $p/4$

I've calculated this with various $P(A)$ forms and multiplied the $P$'s together and even substituted each answer into $p$. But none seem to make sense.

Comment: What is the sum of the probabilities of the three mutually exclusive events?

Comment: Part of the problem. This is a GRE question. There is no sum, no formula or any other information given. Just those 3 p outcomes and those answer choicess.

Comment: if these are the only outcomes what must p+p/2+p/4 be equal to ?

Comment: I would guess it's 1. So the answer would be what gets 1 as a sum. So it would seem to need 1/7, since that equals 1. And any of the others give a total p of 2, 3, 4, and 5. Am I looking at that right?

Comment: Find $p$, not find $p/4$.  Note $1/7+1/7/2+1/7/4$ is much less than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let us give names to everything.  Let our three mutually exclusive and exhaustive events be $A,B,C$ where $Pr(A)=p$, $Pr(B)=\frac{p}{2}$ and $Pr(C)=\frac{p}{4}$.

Since they are mutually exclusive this implies that $A\cap B=A\cap C=B\cap C=\emptyset$ and since they are exhaustive this implies that $A\cup B\cup C=\Omega$, the entire sample space.

We know from probability axioms that $Pr(\Omega)=1$

We also know from inclusion-exclusion principle or from axioms that $Pr(A\cup B\cup C)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)$ as a result of mutual exclusivity.

Combining this information then we learn:

> $p+\frac{p}{2}+\frac{p}{4}=1$

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. I was trying to multiply the outcomes. It makes sense now. Thanks to all for helping an addled brain.